# Measuring interaction between count variables with collinearity

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction

I have 3 groups of people in sequences:
- one gets treatment A 
- one gets treatment B
- one gets no treatment at all

For that I am looking at sequences of Users, where they receive a treatment, but they might have already received one in the past. Treatment A and B are the independent variables.

I have information about the response of a user in this sequence, which treatment he/she received (always either A or B) and the count of the previous received treatment.

The treatment and the past treatment experience are colinear. My question is that how would i construct the GLM/binominal model equation to measure the influence of the previous experience?

```
glm(Response ~ TreatmentA + TreatmentB + PriorA + PriorB + (TreatmentA*PriorA) + 
(TreatmentB*PriorB), family="poisson", data=df))
```

With this solution i get NA NA for the interaction terms, because of the colinearity between the two variables. What do I have to change to make a correct equation?

Illustrative Example:

```
Sequence    User    Response    TreatmentA  TreatmentB  PriorA  PriorB
1_1         1          2            0           0         0       0
1_2         1          5            0           1         0       0
1_3         1          4            0           1         0       1
2_1         2          2            1           0         0       0
2_2         2          0            0           1         1       0
2_3         2          1            1           0         1       1
```

Comment: I think you might have an easier time if you code the variables as factors instead of variable indicators, i.e. treatment and prior take on value $A$, $B$, $P$ (placebo). Then you'll have `glm(Response ~ Treatment + Prior + Treatment*Prior, family="poisson", data=df))`

Also you have the same user getting multiple treatments?

Comment: factors might be a solution, i will have a look at that. In this case you would make the treatments factors and leave the Prior as a count? generally, i would like to include the effect from prior received treatments. Yes, I chose the term treatments to make it more understandable. It is a already existing dataset from a platform not a medical experiment or similar i set up.